# Firebase Analytics in Flutter when using StoreConnector to display new screen

Tags: flutter, screen, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to add Firebase Analytics in Flutter to my Widget but I'm using StoreConnector to display 2 different screens Alpha and Beta. How can I put analytics to track screen changes?

```
class MyWidgetPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StoreConnector<AppState, MyViewModel>(
      converter: (store) => myViewModel.create(store),
      builder: (context, viewModel) {
        return _body(context, viewModel);
      },
    );
  }

  _body(BuildContext context, MyViewModel viewModel) {
    if (viewModel.withLoading) return _loading();
    if (viewModel.withAlphaContent) return _contentAlpha(context, viewModel);
    if (viewModel.withBetaContent) return _contentBeta(context, viewModel);
    if (viewModel.withRetry) return _retry(context);
  }

...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to use the [onDidChange](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_redux/latest/flutter_redux/StoreConnector/onDidChange.html) callback as follows:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();
    return StoreConnector<AppState, MyViewModel>(
      converter: (store) => myViewModel.create(store),
      onDidChange: (viewModel) {
        if (viewModel.withAlphaContent) {
         analytics.setCurrentScreen(screenName: 'alpha content');
        } 
        if (viewModel.withBetaContent) {
         analytics.setCurrentScreen(screenName: 'beta content');
        }
      },
      builder: (context, viewModel) {
        return _body(context, viewModel);
      },
    );
  }
```